# Python NLTK formatting test set

Tags: python, nltk

I have been working on this classifier, and it seems like it almost works. The only problem I am having is the test set.

```
train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'labeledTrainData.tsv'), header=0, \
                    delimiter="\t", quoting=3)

test = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'testData.tsv'), header=0, delimiter="\t", \
               quoting=3)

documents = []
for review in train.values:
    sentiment = 'pos' if review[1] == 1 else 'neg'
    split = review[2].split(), sentiment
    for word in split[0]:
        word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
    documents.append(split)

word_features = nltk.FreqDist(chain(*[i for i, j in documents]))
word_features = list(word_features.keys())[:100]

train_set = [({i: (i in tokens) for i in word_features}, tag) for tokens, tag in documents[:1000]]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier
classifier.train(train_set)

print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test))
classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)
```

So examples I find, there is one set that is being used and split for training in like a 90/10 ratio. Here I actually have two different datasets (one labeled, one test).

The train_set (shortened version shown below) is a list of tuples with bool values saying if the word is in the word_keys and if the review is positive or negative:

```
 [({'beautician,': False, 'hubris,': False, '/>BTW:': False, 'nondenominational': False, 'diapered,': False, 'matter).': False, 'fascist\\"': False, 'Russian,gay': False, '/>\\"Ladies': False, 'purport': False, 'locker-room': False, 'Enjoy"': False, 'exposition': False, 'decisions\\"': False, 'N(n***as)': False, 'Duhllywood),': False, 'cataclysmic': False, 'reviews,': False, 'marry;': False, 'Gordon),': False, 'now-nostalgic': False, 'avoid!!!!"': False, 'coin;': False, 'infiltrators': False, 'smalltime': False, "`knows'": False, 'callous': False, 'actors...it': False, 'Fox,': False, "'78": False, 'Givney': False, 'cinematography):': False, 'misconstrued,': False, 'bathing;': False, 'Hepburn,': False, 'noise,': False, 'BG´s.': False, 'ship.In': False, "'60s.)<br": False, 'Odder': False, 'holes,disgustingly': False, '/>contact': False, 'Croasdell': False, 'trips\\"': False, 'acting.Yet': False, 'firearm.': False, 'businesspeople': False, 'Tomilinson': False, 'ways...<br': False, 'cast...ouch.': False, "Alexandra's": False, "lost.'": False, 'anwers,': False, 'dissertation': False, 'Perry': False, 'phenom': False, '\\"Cleopatra\\",': False, '"Revolt': False, 'secured': False, "romance',": False, 'retentively': False, '/>1/2': False, 'photography/\\"You': False, 'did--': False, 'consulate': False, 'ocurred.': False, 'profession': False, 'insane.': False, 'hysterics)': False, 'UPN.<br': False, 'effects--after': False, 'IMAGE,': False, 'recognizable.<br': False, "Kinky'with": False, 'death\x97it': False, 'Wizard\\"': False, 'pemberton,': False, 'Belting': False, 'boast.': False, 'Schlock!!': False, 'filmed)': False, 'overplotted': False, 'wiring,': False, 'comedy)': False, '`SS': False, 'foibles.': False, 'Germna': False, 'Waverly': False, 'Oxford-educated': False, 'reviews.Anyway': False, 'SANE': False, 'expressively': False, 'cr*p.': False, 'ex-priest': False, 'ITC': False, '/>Sara': False, 'exoticism-oriented': False, "'hello'": False, '"......in': False, 'hesitates': False}, 'neg')]
```

While the test set is still this:

```
               id                                             review
0      "12311_10"  "Naturally in a film who's main themes are of ...
1        "8348_2"  "This movie is a disaster within a disaster fi...
2        "5828_4"  "All in all, this is a movie for kids. We saw ...
3        "7186_2"  "Afraid of the Dark left me with the impressio...
4       "12128_7"  "A very accurate depiction of small time mob l...
...           ...                                                ...
24997    "2531_1"  "I was so disappointed in this movie. I am ver...
24998    "7772_8"  "From the opening sequence, filled with black ...
24999  "11465_10"  "This is a great horror film for people who do...

[25000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Now ofcourse I get the problem that I cannot simply train on this dataset, the original looked just like the test_set above, only there was this sentiment containing a value 1 or 0.
How would I go about training this and using the test set against it? I get that there is some example, but it's not exactly the same as I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

The test set must include the labels (answers). The nltk's evaluation methods expect it, and really there's no  way to measure performance unless you have the labels already. Split your labeled set 90-10 like you saw in the examples, train on the 90%, and reserve the 10% for testing.

Comment: Hmm, did I perhaps miss something? I have three files to use, which is a labeled training set, an unlabled training set, and a testing set. It was my understanding that I trained with the labeled set, and thought the point was to put some unlabeled set (the test set in this case) against it. Where does a set without labels come in then? Ultimately I would like to test it on my own reviews, which will be unlabeled, and label those reviews according to this trained set. Thanks for the answer by the way, appreciate it! @alexis

Comment: You can use your classifier on unlabeled inputs; that's what it's for. But you've got no way to tell if the labels it assigns are correct.